# HDD running at extremely low cache speed

Tags: linux, hard-drive, fedora, speed

Since a few weeks ago my HDD has been extremely slow when reading and writing data from it. I have an internal SSD that runs the main Fedora 34 root system and home, a 500GB internal HDD that has various media files, and a 1TB external USB HDD for music. Here are the hdparms of each respective drive:

```
/dev/nvme0n1:
 Timing cached reads:   14560 MB in  1.99 seconds = 7312.72 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads: 3586 MB in  3.00 seconds = 1195.30 MB/sec

/dev/sda1:
 Timing cached reads:     2 MB in  2.23 seconds = 918.36 kB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads: 334 MB in  3.00 seconds = 111.16 MB/sec


/dev/sdb2:
 Timing cached reads:   13850 MB in  1.99 seconds = 6953.48 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads: 108 MB in  3.00 seconds =  35.94 MB/sec
```

Although this was a few minutes ago, and now trying to call sudo hdparm -tT /dev/sda1 results in:

```
/dev/sda1:
read(2097152) returned 245760 bytes
 Timing buffered disk reads: read() failed: Input/output error
```

My HDD was running perfectly fine until about a week ago, where I found I couldn't save something to the HDD because the software didn't have permissions. Restarting fixed this issue, but it has been painfully slow ever since. I cannot use gnome-disks to run my own SMART checks due to another separate error (udisks-error-quark, 4) but it says that the self self test performed was completed successfully.

Comment: Please ignore any comprehensive binary-type tests and post a smartmontools log file. A bunch of health attributes provides more information than a successfully running self-test.

Comment: Further to what @r2d3 commented, would you post the output of `sudo smartctl -A /dev/sda`?